Attempting to deploy vue vite site and get an error with a module not resolving
I'm attempting to deploy my app to a server using vite(vue).  I saw this was asked here, but it doesn't have an answer.
My vite.config.js is:
export default defineConfig({
  base: "./",
  plugins: [vue(), vueJsx(), vueDevTools()],
  resolve: {
    alias: {
      "@": fileURLToPath(new URL("./src", import.meta.url)),
    },
  },
});

I execute yarn build.
which builds my package: "build": "vite build",
I then push all changes.
The error in my client browser I get is:
Uncaught TypeError: Failed to resolve module specifier "vue". Relative references must start with either "/", "./", or "../".

I assume this has to do with my index.html module found here:
<script type="module" src="src/main.js"></script>

This file is located in src/main.js path.
Any idea what I'm doing wrong? If you need more details as far as the file structures please let me know.  Thank you!

"I then push all changes."  what does this mean?  vite build creates a dist folder with the build files.  These files alone are what need to be moved to the web server.  There shouldn't be any src folder or vue files involved.  Once you have the dist folder, how exactly you deploy will depend on the type of web server or hosting service, which you haven't told us about, but the vite documentation has many examples.

Ah got it! @yoduh THANK YOU BRO!
